# JavaScript For Loop Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I created a spreadsheet for work using Google Sheets. It works well, but I'm trying to enhance it by learning JavaScript, so I wrote a simple copy-paste function that works really well.

To make it easier to change values in the future, I'm trying to add everything to an array and create a for loop. I've never done this before, so forgive me if it looks terrible, but here is the array I created:

```
var rangesAndValues = {
  "0" : {
    range : "C3",
    value : ""
  },
  "1" : {
    range : "C5:C7",
    value : 0
  },
  "2" : {
    range : "C9",
    value : 0
  },
  "3" : {
    range : "G3:G10",
    value : 0
  },
  "4" : {
    range : "J3",
    value : "No"
  },
  "5" : {
    range : "J5",
    value : "No"
  },
  "6" : {
    range : "J7",
    value : 0
  },
  "7" : {
    range : "J9",
    value : 0
  },
  "8" : {
    range : "M3:M10",
    value : 0
  },
  "9" : {
    range : "O3:O10",
    value : 0
  },
  "10" : {
    range : "Q3:Q10",
    value : ""
  },
  "11" : {
    range : "S3:S10",
    value : 0
  }
};
```

I then tried to loop it and console.log it to make sure it worked.

```
rangesAndValues.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element);
});
```

I got this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: rangesAndValues.forEach is not a function at window.onload
```

Eventually I'm going to want it to loop a function for 0-11, and another loop for 1-11 (skipping 0).

I'm not sure how to skip the first one when it does work either, so brownie points if you answer that too. Thanks!!

Comment: `forEach` is an array method here `rangesAndValues` is an object

Comment: I'm very new to JavaScript, so I'm bad with terminology. What does this mean?

Comment: Your `rangesAndValues` object could easily be turned into an arraylike-object by adding a `length: 12` property, then you can get a real array as `Array.from(ranhesAndValues)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forEach is a method on the prototype of an Array, but you have an Object there. You can get the keys of your object, loop through them, and get the value by key, like so:

```
var keys = Object.keys(rangesAndValues)

keys.forEach(function(key){
    var element = rangeAndValues[key];
    console.log(element);
});
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much! I thought I was creating an array. Why did I end up with an object?

Comment: @heelercs Just FYI, this is the original gangster way of doing this (before ES2015). Some of the answers with for...in and Object.values() are more "modern". A good JavaScripter can do it all ways - good luck on your journey :)

Answer (score 0):

You need `for..in` to loop through an object

```js
var rangesAndValues = {
  "0": {
    range: "C3",
    value: ""
  },
  "1": {
    range: "C5:C7",
    value: 0
  },
  "2": {
    range: "C9",
    value: 0
  },
  "3": {
    range: "G3:G10",
    value: 0
  },
  "4": {
    range: "J3",
    value: "No"
  },
  "5": {
    range: "J5",
    value: "No"
  },
  "6": {
    range: "J7",
    value: 0
  },
  "7": {
    range: "J9",
    value: 0
  },
  "8": {
    range: "M3:M10",
    value: 0
  },
  "9": {
    range: "O3:O10",
    value: 0
  },
  "10": {
    range: "Q3:Q10",
    value: ""
  },
  "11": {
    range: "S3:S10",
    value: 0
  }
};


for (let keys in rangesAndValues) {
  console.log(rangesAndValues[keys])

}
```

Comment: This fixed it as well! I'm a little confused with the difference between an object and an array, but I suppose that's what google is for :P Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use array method `forEach` on an object

to iterate over object values you can do

```
Object.values(rangesAndValues).forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element);
});
```

`Object.values` give you an array and then you can use `forEach`